# Passing integers in Prolog rules

Tags: variables, prolog, arguments

I'm quite new to Prolog and I'm currently struggling with passing integers as arguments of one rule into another rule in SWI-Prolog. For example:

```
left(B) :- B is B - 1.
```

...

```
cond2(X) :- X = left(4).
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're illustrating at least three fundamental misunderstandings about Prolog. (1) `B is B - 1` will always fail because, in Prolog, this is saying that you have a value, `B` which is the same as the value `B - 1` which is, of course, not possible.(2) In Prolog, predicates do not return values. They either succeed or fail. So `X = left(4)` doesn't "call" `left`.(3) `=/2` is not an assignment operator. It's a unification operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```
left(A,B) :- B is A - 1.
```

...

```
cond2(X) :- left(4,X).
```

Then `cond2(X)` should return `X = 3`.